# creating a table with null constraint in SQL but have constraint

Tags: sql, constraints, create-table

I want to create a table that column value would be >0 and it can be null.

when I am doing this on the creation of table column

```
CREATE TABLE Ship
  (
    SITE_ID         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Ship_CATEGORY  VARCHAR2(50)  CHECK (WRECK_CATEGORY IN ('Military','Government','Passenger', 'Unknown', 'Commercial')),
    Ship_TYPE      VARCHAR2(100) ,
    Ship_TONNAGE   INTEGER CHECK ((WRECK_TONNAGE>0) AND WRECK_TONNAGE IS NULL) ,
    Ship_CAUSE     VARCHAR2(100) NULL CHECK (WRECK_CAUSE IN ('Fire', 'Collision','Unknown',' Deliberate', 'Explosion',' Attack', 'Other')),
    Ship_DATESUNK  DATE NULL,
    Ship_CONDITION VARCHAR2(50) NULL CHECK (WRECK_CONDITION IN ('Excellent', 'Moderate','Poor', 'Very Poor')),
    CONSTRAINT SHIPWRECK_PK PRIMARY KEY (SITE_ID)
  );
```

in the line "Ship_TONNAGE   INTEGER CHECK ((WRECK_TONNAGE>0) AND WRECK_TONNAGE IS NULL) ,"
when i am inserting null value to this column, it violates the constraint. how i create my table as it satisfy the condition? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the check constraint from an `and` to an `or`:

```
CHECK ((WRECK_TONNAGE>0) or WRECK_TONNAGE IS NULL)
```

Your constraints are referencing the wrong columns, WRECK* instead of SHIP*.  Try this definition statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Ship
  (
    SITE_ID         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Ship_CATEGORY  VARCHAR2(50)  CHECK (SHIP_CATEGORY IN ('Military','Government','Passenger', 'Unknown', 'Commercial')),
    Ship_TYPE      VARCHAR2(100) ,
    Ship_TONNAGE   INTEGER CHECK ((SHIP_TONNAGE>0) or SHIP_TONNAGE IS NULL) ,
    Ship_CAUSE     VARCHAR2(100) NULL CHECK (SHIP_CAUSE IN ('Fire', 'Collision','Unknown',' Deliberate', 'Explosion',' Attack', 'Other')),
    Ship_DATESUNK  DATE NULL,
    Ship_CONDITION VARCHAR2(50) NULL CHECK (SHIP_CONDITION IN ('Excellent', 'Moderate','Poor', 'Very Poor')),
    CONSTRAINT SHIPWRECK_PK PRIMARY KEY (SITE_ID)
  );
```

Comment: Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02290: check constraint (SYS_C00421597) violated
02290. 00000 -  "check constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    The values being inserted do not satisfy the named check
           
*Action:   do not insert values that violate the constraint.

Comment: YES, i EDITED THAT, BUT i STILL HAVING ERRORS THAT VIOLATES THE CONSTRAINT AS ABOVE.

Comment: @BolorCh . . . It works for me at SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/351d2/13).

Comment: Now I found my error I created constraint as ' Deliberate' (with space) and then tried to insert value as 'Deliberate' (without space) that is why I had errors. Thanks guys